# Plugin Expires Headers - W3 Total Cache

Tags: plugins, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

Using the [Google PageSpeed Online](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com), it looks like the CSS/Images/JS files of most of my plugins (including wp-nivo-slider) do not get their expires-headers set. Is there a solution for this so that W3 Total Cache will set the expires headers on all the media on my page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your hosting provider offer `mod_expires`. Because many shared hosting providers doesn't offer `mod_expires` . Just contact your hosting support.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `Performance` > `Browser Cache` > `General` > `Set expires header` is checked.

Comment: Yes it is. Using the PageSpeed tool I can see that only the assets associated with plugins are not getting the expires headers set.